# How can I group N items into 6 random groups so the sum is always the same?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to generate an array with 6 elements where the sum is always N. Only positive integers.

```
var arr = generateArray();
arr.length === 6; //always true
arr.reduce((a,b) => a + b) === 16; //also always true
```

Basically a more elegant way of performing this:

```
rndInt = (max) => Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max)),
rndAssign = (piles, items) => {
    let groups = new Int8Array(piles);
    for (i = 0; i < items; i++) {
        groups[rndInt(piles)]++
    }
    return groups
},
```

Comment: what have you tried? what does not work? do you have negative numbers or same values?

Comment: I have no idea how to do this or how to validate that I did it right. Statistics is tricky...

Comment: i habe no idea, how the random data should look like.

Comment: @NinaScholz updated question with an example that I feel is very bulky.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
const generateArray = (sum = 16, groupsQty = 6) => {
  this.currentSum = 0;
  // create empty array of given length and populate it with items in sum not exceeding given sum
  return Array.from({length: groupsQty}).reduce((res, curr, ind) => {
    const item = ind === groupsQty - 1 ? sum - this.currentSum : Math.floor(Math.random() * (sum + 1 - this.currentSum));
    // store current sum
    this.currentSum += item;
    return [
      ...res, 
      item
    ]
  }, [])
};

const arr = generateArray();
console.log(arr);
console.log('LENGTH:', arr.length);
console.log('SUM:', arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could take an array with values,

- `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]` or
- `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]`,

depending on if you want zero as well and use a brte force method to get any possible combinations of the values which have a sum of `16` by taking six elements.

For a further selection, you may pick a random array. This random value is normally distributed.

**The result may needs a bit longer to run.**

```js
function get6(values) {

    function iter(temp) {
        return function (v) {
            var t = temp.concat(v);
            if (t.length === 6) {
                if (t.reduce(add) === 16) {
                    result.push(t);
                }
                return;
            }
            values.forEach(iter(t));
        };
    }
    
    const
        add = (a, b) => a + b,
        result = [];

    values.forEach(iter([]));
    return result;
}

var small = get6([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]),
    big = get6([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16]);

console.log(small.length);                //  3003
console.log(small.map(a => a.join(' ')));
console.log(big.length);                  // 20349
console.log(big.map(a => a.join(' ')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```